# Ceiling and floor relation property

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it true the following equality for A and B belonging to integers (Z), rationals (Q), reals (R) or complex(C)?

$\lceil A - \dfrac{A}{B}\rceil = A - \lfloor \dfrac{A}{B}\rfloor$

Thank you in advance

Comment: to format ceilings and floors, use `\lceil    \rceil` and `\lfloor   \rfloor`.  What do you mean "true for ... *any space*?"  Division doesn't necessarily make sense in arbitrary spaces, neither does ceiling and floor functions... Do you mean to ask specifically for real numbers $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Thank you so much, I will edit it to clarify the question.

Comment: What is the floor function of an arbitrary complex number?  What is $\lfloor 0.5+0.5i\rfloor$?  $\Bbb C$ is not an ordered field and so there is no concept of "less than."  For rationals and reals, the expression on the left will be an integer, but when $A$ is not an integer the expression on the right is not an integer and therefore could not possibly be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x$ an integer and $y$ any real number, the following is true: $\lceil x + y\rceil = x + \lceil y\rceil$

Furthermore, for $y$ any real number, the following is true:  $\lceil -y\rceil = -\lfloor y\rfloor$

Each of these two properties are easy to prove.  I suggest you try to prove them yourself.

Note from here that for $x$ an integer and $y$ any real number, the above two properties imply that $\lceil x -y\rceil = x + \lceil -y\rceil = x-\lfloor y\rfloor$

From this we see that for $A$ an integer and $B$ any nonzero real number we have that $\left\lceil A - \frac{A}{B}\right\rceil = A-\left\lfloor \frac{A}{B}\right\rfloor$.

This specifically works when $A$ is an integer.

When $A$ is not an integer however and is instead a non-integer real number, one has the left hand side $\left\lceil A - \frac{A}{B}\right\rceil$ is an integer however the right hand side is $A-\left\lfloor \frac{A}{B}\right\rfloor$ which is a non-integer plus an integer which is a non-integer and the equality is therefore false.  (*for specific counter-example $\left\lceil \pi - \frac{\pi}{1}\right\rceil = 0$ but $\pi - \left\lfloor \frac{\pi}{1}\right\rfloor \approx 0.141592\dots$*)

We see then that the proposed equation is true for real numbers $A$ and $B$ **if and only if** $A$ is an integer.

The concept of the floor function does not generalize to the complex numbers and so the question is meaningless to ask in relation to that.

Comment: You are totally right, I did not think it correctly, thank you for your quick response